# undefined method 'imageable_type' for Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to use a polymorphic `Photo` model to handle images for different models. Each `imageable_type` has different criteria. Type `Item` will have versioning and be public, while type `User` will have encryption and be stored in a private S3 bucket. I figured I could do something like this:

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
 if imageable_type == "Item"
  include ImageUploader::Attachment(:image)
 elsif imageable_type == "User"
  #do something else
 end
    
 belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
 validates_presence_of :image
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :photos, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :photos, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

But doing this gives the error: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'imageable_type' for Photo (call 'Photo.connection' to establish a connection):Class)`.

How can I apply different processes to a polymorphic model depending on the type of its association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work because your code is defined on the class but not on the instance. The class does of course not have an `imageable_type` attribute, only the instances do have it.

Depending on what you want to do you need to move this to a method like this.

```rb
class Photo
  def upload #
    if imageable_type == "Item"
      #do something
    elsif imageable_type == "User"
      #do something else
     end
  end
end
```

We would need to have more information what you mean with `criteria` though to come up with an appropriate solution here.

Comment: in my case, i'm using Shrine to upload images and Lockbox to encrypt when needed. i got this little line here: `include ImageUploader::Attachment(:image)`, which uploads to S3 and creates versions. but i would like to add additional arguments (encrypt and store in private S3) depending on the imageable type

Comment: You can't do that as you need to do this on class level and on class level you just don't know the imageable type. One approach could be to subclass it with `SecurePhoto` which would include the attachment with the encrypted options.

Comment: i ended up just making a whole new class. i'll most likely take your approach in my refactor. thank you!!!